# How to improve Coded UI playback stability

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, mtm

I noticed that Coded UI test case playback is working inconsistently depending on the machine and environment. Specifically say I have a test case which worked fine on one machines but it started keep failing on another machine.

**Where is it failing ?**

I have few combo boxes in the web page and coded to set values for these controls. I have few other controls which are coded in the same way but they works successfully in all iterations.

**How do I populate combo boxes ?**

MyTab.MyCombo.SelectedItem = data

**What is happening ?**
the above line of code fails inconstantly

1. If I tried 5 times, then it fails 3-4 times
2. After I added the below command, successful rates increased but it still fails.

   MyTab.MyCombo.WaitForControlReady()
3. I added Mouse.Click(MyTab.MyCombo) before setting value - successful rate increased but it still fails

**It was successful in all iterations after adding the below command**

Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads

When I set to WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads it degrades the performance of playback painfully, so I don't want to use it.

**What about using WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreads**
It did not give any impact.

Experts please provide some suggestions or help me to fix this.

Comment: In CodedUi, sometimes you need to look back to fix the failing statement.  As you mentioned it was working on adding `WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads`, I am just wondering what was the previous step to this statement `MyTab.MyCombo.SelectedItem = data`. Was it some dialog window? or page load?

Comment: Thanks SarkarG, I noticed that the original code before the statement MyTab.MyCombo.SelectedItem = data is performing lot of actions and calling other services. As you mentioned one or more of those statements might be affecting MyTab.MyCombo.SelectedItem = data. Looks like I need to troubleshoot more. Thanks for the insight.